# How to add an icon to a button at the bottom right corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know how to use font-awesome and some other css files to get an icon in a button something like the images below.

[image] [image]

But now My requirement is to have that icon at the bottom right corner of a button. Something like...

[image]

I am Using bootstrap and font-awesome.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>

This is how I use to get the icon in a button.

but I need it to be at the right corner of this button

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create a css class like this and assign it to the icon `span`:

```
.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Additionally the button needs to have `position: relative;` assigned, so that the absolute positioned icons coordinates are relative to the button.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8a2jbp7f/2/

If you want a rotated caret like in your image use text roation like @BenW posted.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info... This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/4n8vydfw/) for which i want to apply that change

Answer (score 1):

As [Mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1696795/mario-a) and [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679790/ben-w) has suggested, I have modified the code in my fiddle to get what i wanted

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
My Contacts <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Css

```
button {
    margin:20px;
    position: relative;
}
.caret {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: 0px;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Final [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/4n8vydfw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with css text rotation!? 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

Comment: Can you elaborate how text rotation can help solve the question of putting icon in a button?

Comment: Thanks for the link... It helped me in rotating the icon as i wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
.btmRight .fa-plus {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Add this style and check.